# Unable to format my PC running Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, usb, installation

I am unable to format my PC from windows bootable USB. The USB is working fine on my laptop. When I start my computer and insert the bootable USB, underscore (_) is just blinking on my screen and nothing else. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to quote [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes)

> This can have several reasons:
>
> - The device is not bootable.
> - The deivce is not bootable unless it was present early.
> - The computer does not support booting from that type.
> - The computer does not support booting from that type via a specific port.
> - The BIOS fails to recognise it at all.

You need to make sure you did everything correctly:

1. prepare your USB drive to be bootable and to contain the installation
2. plug the USB drive in (PC is off)
3. turn on the PC
4. press the key to go to BIOS (go [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm) if you don't know what it is)
5. change the boot sequence
6. save and reboot

Now it should boot. Please note that this is very generic; you will have to do other thing to get it working.

Comment: I think we can rule out the device not being bootable since he says it works on other systems.

Comment: I can't really tell from his post if the USB is just working fine, or if it boots fine on his laptop.

Comment: Hmm, true, although I assume when he's talking specifically about one system not booting he confirmed that the other one boots from the same USB drive/stick.

Answer (score 0):

Use an USB drive to format+install your OS.
To make a bootable usb drive with Windows on it I recommended using Windows USB/DVD Download Tool: http://wudt.codeplex.com/

Comment: His problem is that he's unable to boot his PC from a *known working* Windows bootable USB, and your advice is to "Use an USB drive to format+install your OS"? Wow, talk about obvious.